# How do I change an object attribute based off of a path property array in another object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently unsure as to how to edit one of my objects in my javascript (React JS) program. I am implementing web sockets into my program, and so I am receiving an object that I need to use to edit another object in my program.

Here are the two summarized objects (with only updated properties included):

```
objectWeAreEditingWith = {
    path: [
        "playerStatuses",
        "id1"                         //really is an id like "b02a507f-31..."
    ],
    value: [
        true,
        "Random"
    ]
}

objectWeAreEditing = {
    property1: ...
    property2: ...
    ...
    playerStatuses: {
        id1: [
            false,
            "Generalist"
        ]
    }
    ...
    moreProperties: ...
}
```

Some details about the objects. The "objectWeAreEditingWith" will always only have a path and value property. The path property just contains the keys that are required access the correct key in "objectWeAreEditing". The value property just contains the variable values to change in the key that was detailed in the path property. "ObjectWeAreEditing" can contain any number of properties. Another thing to note is that the values in the array "value" is always in the same order (and size) as the property we are targeting in "objectWeAreEditing". "path", "value", and "id1" could techincally be any size (very long path / many variables), but id1 and value will always have the same length / have the values in the same order like I said before.

For this case, I am trying to do:

```
objectWeAreEditing[playerStatuses][id1][0] = objectWeAreEditingWith[value][0];
```

AND

```
objectWeAreEditing[playerStatuses][id1][1] = objectWeAreEditingWith[value][1];
```

The problem is that, of course, I don't know that I am editing:

```
objectWeAreEditing[playerStatuses][id1]
```

because this path is given by "objectWeAreEditingWith".
I also don't know that I am only editing:

```
objectWeAreEditing[playerStatuses][id1][0];
```

AND

```
objectWeAreEditing[playerStatuses][id1][1];
```

because the amount of variables I am editing is given in "objectWeAreEditingWith".

The solution for the second portion is to go into the "value" property and check its length and iterate through that many variables inside of (id1 in this case). I do not, however, have any clue how to iterate through a path of keys inside of an object.

Comment: IS your question is how to iterate an object?

Comment: oh i think i understand you want to set data in `objectWeAreEditing` depending on objectWeAreEditingWith

Comment: I suppose it is how to edit (via iterating) an attribute of an object with a list of keys provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  set data in `object2` depending on `object1`, one solution is:

```
let object1 = {
    path: [
        "playerStatuses",
        "id1"               
    ],
    value: [
        true,
        "Random"
    ]
};
let object2 = {
    property1: true,
    property2: true,
    playerStatuses: {
        id1: [
            false,
            "Generalist"
        ]
    }
};
console.log(object2);
(function setObjectFrom(object1, object2) {
  var i = 0;
  if (object1.path.length <= 0) {
    throw "Cannot set empty path";
  }
  var currentToKey = object1.path[i];


  (function walkerObject(object, value) {
    for (let key in object) {
       if (key == currentToKey) {
         if (object1.path.length-i <= 1) {
           object[key] = value;
         }
         else {
           i++;
           currentToKey = object1.path[i];
           walkerObject(object[key], value); // call itself
         }
       }
    } 
  })(object2, object1.value);
})(object1, object2);

console.log(object2);
```

Here:
A function (`setObjectFrom`) is defined to set an attribute of a `object2` depending of `object1.path` and `object1.value`.  It define another function named `walkerObject`. This function does the following: each time it find a value of `path` (let name it vPath) as a key of `object1`, it verify if it is the last key:

- When it is the last key, it set `value` as value of `object2[vPath]`
- If it is not the last key, the walkerObject call itself again looking for the next value of `path`, but with `object2[vPath]` as object2

This function is not bullet proof, that mean, it does not handle error such as `object1.path` is not found inside `object2` and others case.

[Corresponding jsBin](https://jsbin.com/nalubes/1/edit?js,console)